# Retrieve data from api and put into room

Tags: kotlin, retrofit2, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

I'm facing this error when putting data into room from my api:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to invoke no-args constructor for
> retrofit2.Call<com.example.youbank.models.Customer>. Registering an
> InstanceCreator with Gson for this type may fix this problem.

I have looked up this issue and tried multiple things to fix it but, i think there is something else wrong, which probably comes down to my lack of knowledge on this subject.
Sorry for the big copypaste of my code but i don't know where to fix this problem so im just including what i think is needed.

HomeScreenFragment:

```
class HomeScreenMotionFragment: Fragment(), CoroutineScope {

private var job: Job = Job()

override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
    get() = Dispatchers.IO + job

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    job.cancel()
}



private var _binding: FragmentHomeScreenMotionBinding? = null
private val binding get() = _binding!!

private val vm: CustomerViewModel by activityViewModels()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    launch {
        vm.addCustomerToRoomDB(14)
    }
}
```

CustomerViewModel:

```
    class CustomerViewModel(application: Application): AndroidViewModel(application) {
    
    val readCustomer: LiveData<RoomCustomer>
    val readAccount: LiveData<List<RoomAccount>>
    val readCard: LiveData<List<RoomCard>>

    private val customerRepo: CustomerRepository
    private val accountRepo: AccountRepository
    private val cardRepo: CardRepository

    var cus: Customer
    var a = listOf<Account>()
    var cards = listOf<Card>()

    init {
        cus = Customer()

        val customerDao = CustomerDatabase.getDatabase(application).customerDao()
        customerRepo = CustomerRepository(customerDao)
        readCustomer = customerRepo.readCustomer

        val accountDao = CustomerDatabase.getDatabase(application).accountDao()
        accountRepo = AccountRepository(accountDao)
        readAccount = accountRepo.readAccounts

        val cardDao = CustomerDatabase.getDatabase(application).cardDao()
        cardRepo = CardRepository(cardDao)
        readCard = cardRepo.readCards
    }

    suspend fun addCustomerToRoomDB(id: Int) {
        val service: CustomerService = ApiService.buildService(CustomerService::class.java)
        val req: Call<Customer> = service.getCustomerById(id)

        req.enqueue(object: Callback<Customer> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<Customer>, response: Response<Customer>) {
                cus = response.body()!!
                a = response.body()!!.accounts
                cards = response.body()!!.accounts[0].cards
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Customer>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.d("get customer failed", t.cause.toString())
            }
        })

        val roomCustomer = RoomCustomer(
            0, cus.customerId, cus.fullName, cus.phone, cus.address, cus.birthday.toString(), cus.email, cus.password)
        val roomAccount = RoomAccount(0, a[0].accountId, a[0].accountNumber, a[0].accountType, a[0].balance)
        val roomCard = RoomCard(
            0, cards[0].cardId, cards[0].cardNumber, cards[0].ccv, cards[0].expirationDate, cards[0].cardType,
            cards[0].cardStatus)

        // Adding customer to roomdatabase
        customerRepo.addCustomer(roomCustomer)
        accountRepo.addAccounts(roomAccount)
        cardRepo.addCards(roomCard)
    }
}
```

CustomerService:

```
interface CustomerService {
    @GET("Customers/{id}")
    suspend fun getCustomerById(@Path("id") id: Int): Call<Customer>
}
```

My models:

```
class Customer {
    var customerId: Int = -1
    var fullName: String = ""
    var phone: String = ""
    var address: String = ""
    var birthday: Date? = null
    var email: String = ""
    var password: String = ""
    lateinit var accounts: List<Account>
}
class Account {
    var accountId: Int = -1
    var accountNumber: String = generateAccNumber()
    lateinit var accountType: AccountType
    var balance: Double = 0.0
    lateinit var cards: List<Card>
}
class Card {
    var cardId: Int = -1
    var cardNumber: Int = -1
    var ccv: Int = -1
    lateinit var expirationDate: String
    lateinit var cardType: CardType
    lateinit var cardStatus: CardStatus
}
```

My repositories:

```
class CustomerRepository(private val customerDao: CustomerDao) {

    val readCustomer: LiveData<RoomCustomer> = customerDao.getCustomer()

    fun addCustomer(c: RoomCustomer) {
        customerDao.addCustomer(c)
    }
}
class AccountRepository (private val accountDao: AccountDao) {

    val readAccounts: LiveData<List<RoomAccount>> = accountDao.getAccounts()

    fun addAccounts(a: RoomAccount) {
        accountDao.addAccount(a)
    }
}
class CardRepository(private val cardDao: CardDao) {

    val readCards: LiveData<List<RoomCard>> = cardDao.getCards()

    fun addCards(c: RoomCard) {
        cardDao.addCards(c)
    }
}
```

My daos:

```
@Dao
interface CustomerDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM customer_table")
    fun getCustomer(): LiveData<RoomCustomer>

    @Insert
    fun addCustomer(c: RoomCustomer)

    @Delete
    fun deleteCustomer(c: RoomCustomer)
}
@Dao
interface AccountDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM accounts_table")
    fun getAccounts(): LiveData<List<RoomAccount>>

    @Insert
    fun addAccount(a: RoomAccount)

    @Delete
    fun deleteAccount(a: RoomAccount)
}
@Dao
interface CardDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM cards_table")
    fun getCards(): LiveData<List<RoomCard>>

    @Insert
    fun addCards(c: RoomCard)

    @Delete
    fun deleteCard(c: RoomCard)
}
```

My room models:

```
@Entity(tableName = "customer_table")
data class RoomCustomer(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val CID: Int,
    val customerId: Int,
    val fullName: String,
    val phone: String,
    val address: String,
    val birthday: String,
    val email: String,
    val password: String
)
@Entity(tableName = "accounts_table")
data class RoomAccount(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val AID: Int,
    val accountId: Int,
    val accountNumber: String,
    val accountType: AccountType,
    val balance: Double
)
@Entity(tableName = "cards_table")
data class RoomCard(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val CID: Int,
    val cardId: Int,
    val cardNumber: Int,
    val ccv: Int,
    val expirationDate: String,
    val cardType: CardType,
    val cardStatus: CardStatus
)
```

Comment: did you check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60494628/java-lang-runtimeexception-unable-to-invoke-no-args-constructor-for-retrofit2-c

Comment: https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/3226 and this one as well